# Where to ask question about CSS themes

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question which is technically programming related, but since it has to do with a particular CSS theme, I'm worried it might not be appropriate for SO. Where do you think I should ask a question like this:

> I am using the [Black
>   Label](http://themeforest.net/item/black-label-fullscreen-video-image-background/336949)
>   theme and on the [porfolio
>   page](http://themeforest.net/item/black-label-fullscreen-video-image-background/full_screen_preview/336949)
>   you can click on a picture and a bigger picture comes up. This is in
>   the form of a slide show, and you can use left or right to go to the
>   previous or next picture. However, there is always only one picture,
>   so it wraps around every time. Using wordpress there is only an option
>   to add a featured image, but no option to add other images. I find it
>   strange that a slideshow would only allow one image. How do I add more
>   images to each portfolio category?

Comment: @Asad thanks asad. If that is in the form of an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Stack Exchange site specifically devoted to questions about WordPress development: [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

As with all sites, before you post anything you should:

1. Read their [FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq?mnu=1)
2. Look at other questions on the site to get a feel for its intended scope
3. Tailor your question so that it is a good fit for their community.

Good luck with your question.